# std::unordered_map using enum and defined class

Tags: c++, class, c++11, enums, unordered-map

I'm trying to define a `std::unordered_map` using an `enum class` as the key and a defined class as the referenced object:

```
std::unordered_map<Dimension, unit, EnumClassHash> SI_Dim;
SI_Dim[Dimension::MASS] = BaseSIUnits::kilogram;
```

`Dimension` is an `enum class` declared in a separate header file as

```
enum class Dimension{MASS, TIME, LENGTH, TEMPERATURE, CURRENT, QUANTITY, ANGLE, FORCE, ENERGY, POWER,
                 AREA, VOLUME, NONDIMENSIONAL};
```

with `EnumClassHash` as a hashing function (which I can post the code for if it's relevant).

`BaseSIUnits::kilogram` is defined a few lines above this as

```
const unit BaseSIUnits::kilogram = unit(1, "kg", Dimension::MASS);
```

which compiles just fine. But the `SI_Dim[Dimension::MASS] = BaseSIUnits::kilogram;` line gives me an error. In QtCreator (my IDE) it says "expected a declaration" and g++ gives the error "SI_Dim does not name a type." Neither of these make any sense to me. Also, when looking at the line in QtCreator, neither `Dimension::MASS` or `BaseSIUnits::kilogram` is highlighted (almost as if they're unrecognized, even though I know they are). I don't have much experience with std::unordered_map, so this is probably some simple syntax error I'm missing. But the syntax looks right to me based on examples I've looked at.

Comment: Sorry, I guess the question isn't clear here. My question is whether there's an obvious syntax error that's preventing the code from compiling.

Comment: Do you have this line `SI_Dim[Dimension::MASS] = BaseSIUnits::kilogram;` outside of a function? You can't just have arbitrary code at namespace scope.

Comment: I do have it outside of a function. I want the unordered_map container to be accessible from other files. How do I do that?

Comment: One option would be to use list initialization - `std::unordered_map<Dimension, unit, EnumClassHash> SI_Dim{{Dimension::MASS, BaseSIUnits::kilogram}};`

Comment: That compiles great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As Praetorian noted in the comment, you can't really have code outside of functions in C++ (except for initializing global/static variables). If you need such code (i.e., code that cannot be written as initialization), then you can write a function `init_si_dim` which is required to be called (once) prior to use. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25864206/running-c-code-outside-of-functions-scope) for a way of automating this through a global object of an ad-hoc class that does the initialization in the constructor.

On a separate direction, the use of an unordered map for your type of `enum`, seems a bit odd. Given that you have so few values, and are not assigning specific integer values to the `enum` values, I think that you're better off with a random-access container, e.g., through [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Consider the following code

```
#include <array>                                                                                                                            

enum class dimension{mass, time, length};

inline constexpr std::size_t dimension_to_index(dimension d)
{
    return static_cast<std::size_t>(d) - static_cast<std::size_t>(dimension::mass);
}

struct foo{};

std::array<foo, 1 + dimension_to_index(dimension::length)> v;

int main()
{
    v[dimension_to_index(dimension::time)];
}
```

We first have the `enum`, then a safe function for converting its values to indices. We then define an `array` object. As you can see in `main`, it's possible now to access the `array` elements via the `enum` values.

Comment: Interesting. I'll look at both of those alternatives.